# Snowflake SQL Statement Pivot will not work with query I am using

Tags: sql, pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, transpose

Below is the Snowflake query.  I know it is ugly but it is what I have to work with here.  The problem is my PIVOT isn't working.  Everything up to that point works but when I try the Pivot I get an error:  invalid identifier 'DRIVERTYPE'.  I need to transpose my results to turn rows into columns based on the DriverType.

```
SELECT CSC, DRIVERTYPE, TEN_MONTHS_TURNOVER FROM 
(
  -- Beginning of Year (Driver Count):
  SELECT 
      CASE
        WHEN A.CSC = 'ABI' THEN 'Abilene'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'ALB' THEN 'Albuquerque'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'AMA' THEN 'Amarillo'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'BOV' THEN 'Bovina'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'DFW' THEN 'Dallas / Fort Worth'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'ELP' THEN 'El Paso'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'HOU' THEN 'Houston'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'ODE' THEN 'Odessa'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'OKC' THEN 'Oklahoma City'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'PHO' THEN 'Phoenix'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'SAN' THEN 'San Antonio'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'TOP' THEN 'Topeka'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'TUL' THEN 'Tulsa'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'WIC' THEN 'Wichita'
      END AS CSC, 
      CASE
        WHEN A.DRIVERTYPE = 'CD' THEN 'Company Driver'
        WHEN A.DRIVERTYPE = 'LO' THEN 'Independent Contractor'
      END AS DRIVERTYPE,
      A.DRIVER_COUNT_BEG_YR, B.YTD_HIRED_DRIVERS, C.YTD_TERMED_DRIVERS, D.DRIVER_COUNT_END_MO, 
      ROUND((A.DRIVER_COUNT_BEG_YR + D.DRIVER_COUNT_END_MO) / 2) AS AVG_DRIVER_COUNT, ROUND(C.YTD_TERMED_DRIVERS / AVG_DRIVER_COUNT, 4) AS TEN_MONTHS_TURNOVER,
      ROUND(TEN_MONTHS_TURNOVER / 10, 4) AS MONTHLY_TURNOVER, ROUND(TEN_MONTHS_TURNOVER * 12 / 10, 4) AS ANNUALIZED_TURNOVER, 
      ROUND(C.YTD_TERMED_DRIVERS / (A.DRIVER_COUNT_BEG_YR + B.YTD_HIRED_DRIVERS) * 1, 4) AS TURNOVER,
      G.COUNTS AS EOY_FORECAST_COUNTS, +EOY_FORECAST_COUNTS - D.DRIVER_COUNT_END_MO AS NEED_TO_HIRE, E.RANGE_HIRED_DRIVERS, F.RANGE_TERMED_DRIVERS
  FROM
  (
  SELECT MPP_Terminal AS CSC, MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE, COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS DRIVER_COUNT_BEG_YR 
  FROM (
        SELECT MPP_Terminal, /* <-- is Join to CSC */
        MPP_Status, 
        MPP_Type1,
        MPP_HireDate,
        MPP_TerminationDT
        FROM "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE" 
        WHERE SUBSTRING(MPP_HIREDATE,1,4) < SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(),1,4) 
        AND SUBSTRING(MPP_TERMINATIONDT,1,4) >= SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(),1,4) 
        AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')   
        ORDER BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
       ) 
  GROUP BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ORDER BY  MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ) A
  LEFT JOIN
  (
  -- Year to Date (Hired Drivers):
  SELECT MPP_Terminal AS CSC, MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE, COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS YTD_HIRED_DRIVERS 
  FROM (
        SELECT MPP_Terminal, /* <-- is Join to CSC */
        MPP_Status, 
        MPP_Type1,
        MPP_HireDate,
        MPP_TerminationDT
        FROM "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE" 
        WHERE SUBSTRING(MPP_HIREDATE,1,4) = SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(),1,4) 
        AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')   
        ORDER BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
       ) 
  GROUP BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ORDER BY  MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ) B ON A.CSC = B.CSC AND A.DRIVERTYPE = B.DRIVERTYPE
  LEFT JOIN
  (
  -- Year to Date (Termed Drivers):
  SELECT MPP_Terminal AS CSC, MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE, COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS YTD_TERMED_DRIVERS
  FROM (
        SELECT MPP_Terminal, /* <-- is Join to CSC */
        MPP_Status, 
        MPP_Type1,
        MPP_HireDate,
        MPP_TerminationDT
        FROM "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE" 
        WHERE SUBSTRING(MPP_TERMINATIONDT,1,4) = SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(),1,4)
        AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')   
        ORDER BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
       ) 
  GROUP BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ORDER BY  MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ) C ON A.CSC = C.CSC AND A.DRIVERTYPE = C.DRIVERTYPE
  LEFT JOIN
  (
  -- End of Month (Driver Count):
  SELECT MPP_Terminal AS CSC, MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE, COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS DRIVER_COUNT_END_MO--, Forecast_Counts 
  FROM (
        SELECT MPP_Terminal, /* <-- is Join to CSC */
        MPP_Status, 
        MPP_Type1,
        MPP_HireDate,
        MPP_TerminationDT
        FROM "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE" 
        WHERE SUBSTRING(MPP_HIREDATE,1,4) <= SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(),1,4) AND SUBSTRING(MPP_HIREDATE,6,2) <= SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(),6,2)
        AND SUBSTRING(MPP_TERMINATIONDT,1,4) >= SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(),1,4) AND SUBSTRING(MPP_TERMINATIONDT,6,2) > SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(),6,2)
        AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')   
        ORDER BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
       ) 
  GROUP BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ORDER BY  MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ) D ON A.CSC = D.CSC AND A.DRIVERTYPE = D.DRIVERTYPE
  LEFT JOIN
  (
  -- Montly/Date Range (Hired Drivers):
  SELECT MPP_Terminal AS CSC, MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE, COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS RANGE_HIRED_DRIVERS 
  FROM (
        SELECT MPP_Terminal, /* <-- is Join to CSC */
        MPP_Status, 
        MPP_Type1,
        MPP_HireDate,
        MPP_TerminationDT
        FROM "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE" 
        WHERE MPP_HIREDATE BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-07-31'
        AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')   
        ORDER BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
      ) 
  GROUP BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ORDER BY  MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ) E ON A.CSC = E.CSC AND A.DRIVERTYPE = E.DRIVERTYPE
  LEFT JOIN
  (
  -- Montly/Date Range (Termed Drivers):
  SELECT MPP_Terminal AS CSC, MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE, COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS RANGE_TERMED_DRIVERS
  FROM (
        SELECT MPP_Terminal, /* <-- is Join to CSC */
        MPP_Status, 
        MPP_Type1,
        MPP_HireDate,
        MPP_TerminationDT
        FROM "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE" 
        WHERE MPP_TERMINATIONDT BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-07-31' 
        AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')   
        ORDER BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
      ) 
  GROUP BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ORDER BY  MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ) F ON A.CSC = F.CSC AND A.DRIVERTYPE = F.DRIVERTYPE
  INNER JOIN "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_DRIVERFORECAST" G ON A.CSC = G.CSC   -- AND A.DRIVERTYPE = E.DRIVERTYPE
  WHERE SUBSTRING(MONTH,1,4) = SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(),1,4) AND SUBSTRING(MONTH,6,2) = 12 /* End of Current Year Forecast */


  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- (Works 3rd Graph) Sub-Total Line Grouping and % Formulas (to get correct Percentages):
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  UNION 

  -- Beginning of Year (Driver Count):
  SELECT  
      CASE
        WHEN A.CSC = 'ABI' THEN 'Abilene'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'ALB' THEN 'Albuquerque'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'AMA' THEN 'Amarillo'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'BOV' THEN 'Bovina'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'DFW' THEN 'Dallas / Fort Worth'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'ELP' THEN 'El Paso'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'HOU' THEN 'Houston'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'ODE' THEN 'Odessa'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'OKC' THEN 'Oklahoma City'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'PHO' THEN 'Phoenix'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'SAN' THEN 'San Antonio'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'TOP' THEN 'Topeka'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'TUL' THEN 'Tulsa'
        WHEN A.CSC = 'WIC' THEN 'Wichita'
      END AS CSC, 
      'Total' AS DRIVERTYPE, --A.DRIVERTYPE, 
      SUM(A.DRIVER_COUNT_BEG_YR) AS DRIVER_COUNT_BEG_YR, SUM(B.YTD_HIRED_DRIVERS) AS YTD_HIRED_DRIVERS, 
      SUM(C.YTD_TERMED_DRIVERS) AS YTD_TERMED_DRIVERS, SUM(D.DRIVER_COUNT_END_MO) AS DRIVER_COUNT_END_MO, 
      SUM(ROUND((A.DRIVER_COUNT_BEG_YR + D.DRIVER_COUNT_END_MO) / 2)) AS AVG_DRIVER_COUNT, 
      ROUND(SUM(C.YTD_TERMED_DRIVERS) / AVG_DRIVER_COUNT, 4) AS TEN_MONTHS_TURNOVER,
      ROUND(TEN_MONTHS_TURNOVER / 10, 4) AS MONTHLY_TURNOVER, ROUND(TEN_MONTHS_TURNOVER * 12 / 10, 4) AS ANNUALIZED_TURNOVER, 
      ROUND(SUM(C.YTD_TERMED_DRIVERS) / (SUM(A.DRIVER_COUNT_BEG_YR) + SUM(B.YTD_HIRED_DRIVERS)) * 1, 4) AS TURNOVER,
      SUM(G.COUNTS) AS EOY_FORECAST_COUNTS, +EOY_FORECAST_COUNTS - SUM(D.DRIVER_COUNT_END_MO) AS NEED_TO_HIRE, 
      SUM(E.RANGE_HIRED_DRIVERS) AS RANGE_HIRED_DRIVERS, SUM(F.RANGE_TERMED_DRIVERS) AS RANGE_TERMED_DRIVERS
  FROM
  (
  SELECT MPP_Terminal AS CSC, MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE, COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS DRIVER_COUNT_BEG_YR 
  FROM (
        SELECT MPP_Terminal, /* <-- is Join to CSC */
        MPP_Status, 
        MPP_Type1,
        MPP_HireDate,
        MPP_TerminationDT
        FROM "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE" 
        WHERE SUBSTRING(MPP_HIREDATE,1,4) < SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(),1,4) 
        AND SUBSTRING(MPP_TERMINATIONDT,1,4) >= SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(),1,4) 
        AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')   
        ORDER BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
       ) 
  GROUP BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ORDER BY  MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ) A
  LEFT JOIN
  (
  -- Year to Date (Hired Drivers):
  SELECT MPP_Terminal AS CSC, MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE, COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS YTD_HIRED_DRIVERS 
  FROM (
        SELECT MPP_Terminal, /* <-- is Join to CSC */
        MPP_Status, 
        MPP_Type1,
        MPP_HireDate,
        MPP_TerminationDT
        FROM "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE" 
        WHERE SUBSTRING(MPP_HIREDATE,1,4) = SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(),1,4) 
        AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')   
        ORDER BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
       ) 
  GROUP BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ORDER BY  MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ) B ON A.CSC = B.CSC AND A.DRIVERTYPE = B.DRIVERTYPE
  LEFT JOIN
  (
  -- Year to Date (Termed Drivers):
  SELECT MPP_Terminal AS CSC, MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE, COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS YTD_TERMED_DRIVERS
  FROM (
        SELECT MPP_Terminal, /* <-- is Join to CSC */
        MPP_Status, 
        MPP_Type1,
        MPP_HireDate,
        MPP_TerminationDT
        FROM "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE" 
        WHERE SUBSTRING(MPP_TERMINATIONDT,1,4) = SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(),1,4)
        AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')   
        ORDER BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
       ) 
  GROUP BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ORDER BY  MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ) C ON A.CSC = C.CSC AND A.DRIVERTYPE = C.DRIVERTYPE
  LEFT JOIN
  (
  -- End of Month (Driver Count):
  SELECT MPP_Terminal AS CSC, MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE, COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS DRIVER_COUNT_END_MO--, Forecast_Counts 
  FROM (
        SELECT MPP_Terminal, /* <-- is Join to CSC */
        MPP_Status, 
        MPP_Type1,
        MPP_HireDate,
        MPP_TerminationDT
        FROM "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE" 
        WHERE SUBSTRING(MPP_HIREDATE,1,4) <= SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(),1,4) AND SUBSTRING(MPP_HIREDATE,6,2) <= SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(),6,2)
        AND SUBSTRING(MPP_TERMINATIONDT,1,4) >= SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(),1,4) AND SUBSTRING(MPP_TERMINATIONDT,6,2) > SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(),6,2)
        AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')   /* CD is Company Driver?, LO is Independent Contractor? */
        ORDER BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
       ) 
  GROUP BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ORDER BY  MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ) D ON A.CSC = D.CSC AND A.DRIVERTYPE = D.DRIVERTYPE
  LEFT JOIN
  (
  -- Monthly/Date Range (Hired Drivers):
  SELECT MPP_Terminal AS CSC, MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE, COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS RANGE_HIRED_DRIVERS 
  FROM (
        SELECT MPP_Terminal, /* <-- is Join to CSC */
        MPP_Status, 
        MPP_Type1,
        MPP_HireDate,
        MPP_TerminationDT
        FROM "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE" 
        WHERE MPP_HIREDATE BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-07-31'
        AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')   
        ORDER BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
      ) 
  GROUP BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ORDER BY  MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ) E ON A.CSC = E.CSC AND A.DRIVERTYPE = E.DRIVERTYPE
  LEFT JOIN
  (
  -- Monthly/Date Range (Termed Drivers):
  SELECT MPP_Terminal AS CSC, MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE, COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS RANGE_TERMED_DRIVERS
  FROM (
        SELECT MPP_Terminal, /* <-- is Join to CSC */
        MPP_Status, 
        MPP_Type1,
        MPP_HireDate,
        MPP_TerminationDT
        FROM "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE" 
        WHERE MPP_TERMINATIONDT BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-07-31'
        AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')   
        ORDER BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
      ) 
  GROUP BY MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ORDER BY  MPP_TERMINAL, MPP_TYPE1
  ) F ON A.CSC = F.CSC AND A.DRIVERTYPE = F.DRIVERTYPE
  INNER JOIN "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_DRIVERFORECAST" G ON A.CSC = G.CSC   -- AND A.DRIVERTYPE = G.DRIVERTYPE
  WHERE SUBSTRING(MONTH,1,4) = SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(),1,4) AND SUBSTRING(MONTH,6,2) = 12 /* End of Current Year Forecast */
  GROUP BY A.CSC --,A.DRIVERTYPE
  ORDER BY CSC, DRIVERTYPE
) H 
PIVOT (
  AVG(TEN_MONTHS_TURNOVER) FOR DRIVERTYPE IN ('Company Driver', 'Independent Contractor', 'Total')
) AS PivotTable
```

Below is how the data looks from everything up to the Pivot:

[image]

I am guessing this is an Alias issue.  I tried doing the top level select with an Alias and using that but no luck.  Also tried A.VarNames, up to H.VarNames but still get the error when trying to use Pivot.  I am open to other ways to get this done.  Would like to see some examples in the answers please.

Comment: Consider defining the main query as a view (without the pivot), then select from that view and apply the pivot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't have your base tables and you indicated the majority of the query works, I wrote a simple test using WITH which provided a pivoted result set.

```
WITH PT (CSC, DRIVERTYPE, TEN_MONTHS_TURNOVER) AS (
        select
            $1 as CSC,
            $2 as DRIVERTYPE,
            $3 as TEN_MONTHS_TURNOVER
        from
            (
                values
                    ('Abilene', 'Company Driver', 0.125),('Abilene', 'Independent Contractor', 0.125),('Abilene', 'Total', 0.125)
            )
    )
SELECT
    *
FROM
    PT 
    PIVOT (
        AVG(TEN_MONTHS_TURNOVER) FOR DRIVERTYPE IN (
            'Company Driver',
            'Independent Contractor',
            'Total'
        )
    ) as P;
```

So, applied it to your query - please see if this works for you:

```
WITH PT (CSC, DRIVERTYPE, TEN_MONTHS_TURNOVER) AS (
    SELECT
        CSC,
        DRIVERTYPE,
        TEN_MONTHS_TURNOVER
    FROM
        (
            -- Beginning of Year (Driver Count):
            SELECT
                CASE
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'ABI' THEN 'Abilene'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'ALB' THEN 'Albuquerque'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'AMA' THEN 'Amarillo'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'BOV' THEN 'Bovina'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'DFW' THEN 'Dallas / Fort Worth'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'ELP' THEN 'El Paso'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'HOU' THEN 'Houston'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'ODE' THEN 'Odessa'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'OKC' THEN 'Oklahoma City'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'PHO' THEN 'Phoenix'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'SAN' THEN 'San Antonio'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'TOP' THEN 'Topeka'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'TUL' THEN 'Tulsa'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'WIC' THEN 'Wichita'
                END AS CSC,
                CASE
                    WHEN A.DRIVERTYPE = 'CD' THEN 'Company Driver'
                    WHEN A.DRIVERTYPE = 'LO' THEN 'Independent Contractor'
                END AS DRIVERTYPE,
                A.DRIVER_COUNT_BEG_YR,
                B.YTD_HIRED_DRIVERS,
                C.YTD_TERMED_DRIVERS,
                D.DRIVER_COUNT_END_MO,
                ROUND(
                    (A.DRIVER_COUNT_BEG_YR + D.DRIVER_COUNT_END_MO) / 2
                ) AS AVG_DRIVER_COUNT,
                ROUND(C.YTD_TERMED_DRIVERS / AVG_DRIVER_COUNT, 4) AS TEN_MONTHS_TURNOVER,
                ROUND(TEN_MONTHS_TURNOVER / 10, 4) AS MONTHLY_TURNOVER,
                ROUND(TEN_MONTHS_TURNOVER * 12 / 10, 4) AS ANNUALIZED_TURNOVER,
                ROUND(
                    C.YTD_TERMED_DRIVERS / (A.DRIVER_COUNT_BEG_YR + B.YTD_HIRED_DRIVERS) * 1,
                    4
                ) AS TURNOVER,
                G.COUNTS AS EOY_FORECAST_COUNTS,
                + EOY_FORECAST_COUNTS - D.DRIVER_COUNT_END_MO AS NEED_TO_HIRE,
                E.RANGE_HIRED_DRIVERS,
                F.RANGE_TERMED_DRIVERS
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                        MPP_Terminal AS CSC,
                        MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE,
                        COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS DRIVER_COUNT_BEG_YR
                    FROM
                        (
                            SELECT
                                MPP_Terminal,
                                /* <-- is Join to CSC */
                                MPP_Status,
                                MPP_Type1,
                                MPP_HireDate,
                                MPP_TerminationDT
                            FROM
                                "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE"
                            WHERE
                                SUBSTRING(MPP_HIREDATE, 1, 4) < SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(), 1, 4)
                                AND SUBSTRING(MPP_TERMINATIONDT, 1, 4) >= SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(), 1, 4)
                                AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')
                            ORDER BY
                                MPP_TERMINAL,
                                MPP_TYPE1
                        )
                    GROUP BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                    ORDER BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                ) A
                LEFT JOIN (
                    -- Year to Date (Hired Drivers):
                    SELECT
                        MPP_Terminal AS CSC,
                        MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE,
                        COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS YTD_HIRED_DRIVERS
                    FROM
                        (
                            SELECT
                                MPP_Terminal,
                                /* <-- is Join to CSC */
                                MPP_Status,
                                MPP_Type1,
                                MPP_HireDate,
                                MPP_TerminationDT
                            FROM
                                "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE"
                            WHERE
                                SUBSTRING(MPP_HIREDATE, 1, 4) = SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(), 1, 4)
                                AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')
                            ORDER BY
                                MPP_TERMINAL,
                                MPP_TYPE1
                        )
                    GROUP BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                    ORDER BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                ) B ON A.CSC = B.CSC
                AND A.DRIVERTYPE = B.DRIVERTYPE
                LEFT JOIN (
                    -- Year to Date (Termed Drivers):
                    SELECT
                        MPP_Terminal AS CSC,
                        MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE,
                        COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS YTD_TERMED_DRIVERS
                    FROM
                        (
                            SELECT
                                MPP_Terminal,
                                /* <-- is Join to CSC */
                                MPP_Status,
                                MPP_Type1,
                                MPP_HireDate,
                                MPP_TerminationDT
                            FROM
                                "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE"
                            WHERE
                                SUBSTRING(MPP_TERMINATIONDT, 1, 4) = SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(), 1, 4)
                                AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')
                            ORDER BY
                                MPP_TERMINAL,
                                MPP_TYPE1
                        )
                    GROUP BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                    ORDER BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                ) C ON A.CSC = C.CSC
                AND A.DRIVERTYPE = C.DRIVERTYPE
                LEFT JOIN (
                    -- End of Month (Driver Count):
                    SELECT
                        MPP_Terminal AS CSC,
                        MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE,
                        COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS DRIVER_COUNT_END_MO --, Forecast_Counts
                    FROM
                        (
                            SELECT
                                MPP_Terminal,
                                /* <-- is Join to CSC */
                                MPP_Status,
                                MPP_Type1,
                                MPP_HireDate,
                                MPP_TerminationDT
                            FROM
                                "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE"
                            WHERE
                                SUBSTRING(MPP_HIREDATE, 1, 4) <= SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(), 1, 4)
                                AND SUBSTRING(MPP_HIREDATE, 6, 2) <= SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(), 6, 2)
                                AND SUBSTRING(MPP_TERMINATIONDT, 1, 4) >= SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(), 1, 4)
                                AND SUBSTRING(MPP_TERMINATIONDT, 6, 2) > SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(), 6, 2)
                                AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')
                            ORDER BY
                                MPP_TERMINAL,
                                MPP_TYPE1
                        )
                    GROUP BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                    ORDER BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                ) D ON A.CSC = D.CSC
                AND A.DRIVERTYPE = D.DRIVERTYPE
                LEFT JOIN (
                    -- Montly/Date Range (Hired Drivers):
                    SELECT
                        MPP_Terminal AS CSC,
                        MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE,
                        COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS RANGE_HIRED_DRIVERS
                    FROM
                        (
                            SELECT
                                MPP_Terminal,
                                /* <-- is Join to CSC */
                                MPP_Status,
                                MPP_Type1,
                                MPP_HireDate,
                                MPP_TerminationDT
                            FROM
                                "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE"
                            WHERE
                                MPP_HIREDATE BETWEEN '2022-07-01'
                                AND '2022-07-31'
                                AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')
                            ORDER BY
                                MPP_TERMINAL,
                                MPP_TYPE1
                        )
                    GROUP BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                    ORDER BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                ) E ON A.CSC = E.CSC
                AND A.DRIVERTYPE = E.DRIVERTYPE
                LEFT JOIN (
                    -- Montly/Date Range (Termed Drivers):
                    SELECT
                        MPP_Terminal AS CSC,
                        MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE,
                        COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS RANGE_TERMED_DRIVERS
                    FROM
                        (
                            SELECT
                                MPP_Terminal,
                                /* <-- is Join to CSC */
                                MPP_Status,
                                MPP_Type1,
                                MPP_HireDate,
                                MPP_TerminationDT
                            FROM
                                "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE"
                            WHERE
                                MPP_TERMINATIONDT BETWEEN '2022-07-01'
                                AND '2022-07-31'
                                AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')
                            ORDER BY
                                MPP_TERMINAL,
                                MPP_TYPE1
                        )
                    GROUP BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                    ORDER BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                ) F ON A.CSC = F.CSC
                AND A.DRIVERTYPE = F.DRIVERTYPE
                INNER JOIN "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_DRIVERFORECAST" G ON A.CSC = G.CSC -- AND A.DRIVERTYPE = E.DRIVERTYPE
            WHERE
                SUBSTRING(MONTH, 1, 4) = SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(), 1, 4)
                AND SUBSTRING(MONTH, 6, 2) = 12
                /* End of Current Year Forecast */
                ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                -- (Works 3rd Graph) Sub-Total Line Grouping and % Formulas (to get correct Percentages):
                ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            UNION
                -- Beginning of Year (Driver Count):
            SELECT
                CASE
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'ABI' THEN 'Abilene'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'ALB' THEN 'Albuquerque'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'AMA' THEN 'Amarillo'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'BOV' THEN 'Bovina'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'DFW' THEN 'Dallas / Fort Worth'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'ELP' THEN 'El Paso'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'HOU' THEN 'Houston'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'ODE' THEN 'Odessa'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'OKC' THEN 'Oklahoma City'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'PHO' THEN 'Phoenix'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'SAN' THEN 'San Antonio'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'TOP' THEN 'Topeka'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'TUL' THEN 'Tulsa'
                    WHEN A.CSC = 'WIC' THEN 'Wichita'
                END AS CSC,
                'Total' AS DRIVERTYPE,
                --A.DRIVERTYPE,
                SUM(A.DRIVER_COUNT_BEG_YR) AS DRIVER_COUNT_BEG_YR,
                SUM(B.YTD_HIRED_DRIVERS) AS YTD_HIRED_DRIVERS,
                SUM(C.YTD_TERMED_DRIVERS) AS YTD_TERMED_DRIVERS,
                SUM(D.DRIVER_COUNT_END_MO) AS DRIVER_COUNT_END_MO,
                SUM(
                    ROUND(
                        (A.DRIVER_COUNT_BEG_YR + D.DRIVER_COUNT_END_MO) / 2
                    )
                ) AS AVG_DRIVER_COUNT,
                ROUND(SUM(C.YTD_TERMED_DRIVERS) / AVG_DRIVER_COUNT, 4) AS TEN_MONTHS_TURNOVER,
                ROUND(TEN_MONTHS_TURNOVER / 10, 4) AS MONTHLY_TURNOVER,
                ROUND(TEN_MONTHS_TURNOVER * 12 / 10, 4) AS ANNUALIZED_TURNOVER,
                ROUND(
                    SUM(C.YTD_TERMED_DRIVERS) / (
                        SUM(A.DRIVER_COUNT_BEG_YR) + SUM(B.YTD_HIRED_DRIVERS)
                    ) * 1,
                    4
                ) AS TURNOVER,
                SUM(G.COUNTS) AS EOY_FORECAST_COUNTS,
                + EOY_FORECAST_COUNTS - SUM(D.DRIVER_COUNT_END_MO) AS NEED_TO_HIRE,
                SUM(E.RANGE_HIRED_DRIVERS) AS RANGE_HIRED_DRIVERS,
                SUM(F.RANGE_TERMED_DRIVERS) AS RANGE_TERMED_DRIVERS
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                        MPP_Terminal AS CSC,
                        MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE,
                        COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS DRIVER_COUNT_BEG_YR
                    FROM
                        (
                            SELECT
                                MPP_Terminal,
                                /* <-- is Join to CSC */
                                MPP_Status,
                                MPP_Type1,
                                MPP_HireDate,
                                MPP_TerminationDT
                            FROM
                                "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE"
                            WHERE
                                SUBSTRING(MPP_HIREDATE, 1, 4) < SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(), 1, 4)
                                AND SUBSTRING(MPP_TERMINATIONDT, 1, 4) >= SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(), 1, 4)
                                AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')
                            ORDER BY
                                MPP_TERMINAL,
                                MPP_TYPE1
                        )
                    GROUP BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                    ORDER BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                ) A
                LEFT JOIN (
                    -- Year to Date (Hired Drivers):
                    SELECT
                        MPP_Terminal AS CSC,
                        MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE,
                        COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS YTD_HIRED_DRIVERS
                    FROM
                        (
                            SELECT
                                MPP_Terminal,
                                /* <-- is Join to CSC */
                                MPP_Status,
                                MPP_Type1,
                                MPP_HireDate,
                                MPP_TerminationDT
                            FROM
                                "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE"
                            WHERE
                                SUBSTRING(MPP_HIREDATE, 1, 4) = SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(), 1, 4)
                                AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')
                            ORDER BY
                                MPP_TERMINAL,
                                MPP_TYPE1
                        )
                    GROUP BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                    ORDER BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                ) B ON A.CSC = B.CSC
                AND A.DRIVERTYPE = B.DRIVERTYPE
                LEFT JOIN (
                    -- Year to Date (Termed Drivers):
                    SELECT
                        MPP_Terminal AS CSC,
                        MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE,
                        COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS YTD_TERMED_DRIVERS
                    FROM
                        (
                            SELECT
                                MPP_Terminal,
                                /* <-- is Join to CSC */
                                MPP_Status,
                                MPP_Type1,
                                MPP_HireDate,
                                MPP_TerminationDT
                            FROM
                                "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE"
                            WHERE
                                SUBSTRING(MPP_TERMINATIONDT, 1, 4) = SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(), 1, 4)
                                AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')
                            ORDER BY
                                MPP_TERMINAL,
                                MPP_TYPE1
                        )
                    GROUP BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                    ORDER BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                ) C ON A.CSC = C.CSC
                AND A.DRIVERTYPE = C.DRIVERTYPE
                LEFT JOIN (
                    -- End of Month (Driver Count):
                    SELECT
                        MPP_Terminal AS CSC,
                        MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE,
                        COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS DRIVER_COUNT_END_MO --, Forecast_Counts
                    FROM
                        (
                            SELECT
                                MPP_Terminal,
                                /* <-- is Join to CSC */
                                MPP_Status,
                                MPP_Type1,
                                MPP_HireDate,
                                MPP_TerminationDT
                            FROM
                                "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE"
                            WHERE
                                SUBSTRING(MPP_HIREDATE, 1, 4) <= SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(), 1, 4)
                                AND SUBSTRING(MPP_HIREDATE, 6, 2) <= SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(), 6, 2)
                                AND SUBSTRING(MPP_TERMINATIONDT, 1, 4) >= SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(), 1, 4)
                                AND SUBSTRING(MPP_TERMINATIONDT, 6, 2) > SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(), 6, 2)
                                AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')
                                /* CD is Company Driver?, LO is Independent Contractor? */
                            ORDER BY
                                MPP_TERMINAL,
                                MPP_TYPE1
                        )
                    GROUP BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                    ORDER BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                ) D ON A.CSC = D.CSC
                AND A.DRIVERTYPE = D.DRIVERTYPE
                LEFT JOIN (
                    -- Monthly/Date Range (Hired Drivers):
                    SELECT
                        MPP_Terminal AS CSC,
                        MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE,
                        COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS RANGE_HIRED_DRIVERS
                    FROM
                        (
                            SELECT
                                MPP_Terminal,
                                /* <-- is Join to CSC */
                                MPP_Status,
                                MPP_Type1,
                                MPP_HireDate,
                                MPP_TerminationDT
                            FROM
                                "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE"
                            WHERE
                                MPP_HIREDATE BETWEEN '2022-07-01'
                                AND '2022-07-31'
                                AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')
                            ORDER BY
                                MPP_TERMINAL,
                                MPP_TYPE1
                        )
                    GROUP BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                    ORDER BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                ) E ON A.CSC = E.CSC
                AND A.DRIVERTYPE = E.DRIVERTYPE
                LEFT JOIN (
                    -- Monthly/Date Range (Termed Drivers):
                    SELECT
                        MPP_Terminal AS CSC,
                        MPP_Type1 AS DRIVERTYPE,
                        COUNT(MPP_TERMINAL) AS RANGE_TERMED_DRIVERS
                    FROM
                        (
                            SELECT
                                MPP_Terminal,
                                /* <-- is Join to CSC */
                                MPP_Status,
                                MPP_Type1,
                                MPP_HireDate,
                                MPP_TerminationDT
                            FROM
                                "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE"
                            WHERE
                                MPP_TERMINATIONDT BETWEEN '2022-07-01'
                                AND '2022-07-31'
                                AND MPP_TYPE1 IN ('CD', 'LO')
                            ORDER BY
                                MPP_TERMINAL,
                                MPP_TYPE1
                        )
                    GROUP BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                    ORDER BY
                        MPP_TERMINAL,
                        MPP_TYPE1
                ) F ON A.CSC = F.CSC
                AND A.DRIVERTYPE = F.DRIVERTYPE
                INNER JOIN "DEV"."PUBLIC"."TMW_DRIVERFORECAST" G ON A.CSC = G.CSC -- AND A.DRIVERTYPE = G.DRIVERTYPE
            WHERE
                SUBSTRING(MONTH, 1, 4) = SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(), 1, 4)
                AND SUBSTRING(MONTH, 6, 2) = 12
                /* End of Current Year Forecast */
            GROUP BY
                A.CSC --,A.DRIVERTYPE
            ORDER BY
                CSC,
                DRIVERTYPE
        )
)
SELECT
   *
FROM
    PT PIVOT (
        AVG(TEN_MONTHS_TURNOVER) FOR DRIVERTYPE IN (
            'Company Driver',
            'Independent Contractor',
            'Total'
        )
    ) AS PivotTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Compressing your query to this:

```
SELECT CSC, DRIVERTYPE, TEN_MONTHS_TURNOVER FROM 
(
    ⋯
) H 
PIVOT (
  AVG(TEN_MONTHS_TURNOVER) FOR DRIVERTYPE IN ('Company Driver', 'Independent Contractor', 'Total')
) AS PivotTable
```

implies a disconnect between the result set columns and the pivot. You may find something like this more workable:

```
SELECT *
(
    ⋯
) H 
PIVOT (
  AVG(TEN_MONTHS_TURNOVER) FOR DRIVERTYPE IN ('Company Driver', 'Independent Contractor', 'Total')
) AS PivotTable
```